# What is the name of the sound-measuring bar on your computer?

Tags: single-word-requests

When testing to see how loud your voice is in a microphone, there is a visual bar/graph that increases as you get louder--what is this called?

I'm not looking for the name of a device the measures sound (e.g. decibel meter).

Comment: sound level meter

Comment: Volume Unit Meter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a representation of a [VU meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter).  In many presentations it could be regarded as an example of a [Skeuomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph), as it's often an imitation of the physical meters of old (for example [Magic eye tubes](http://www.tubeclockdb.com/forum/Builders-Forum/2582-Magic-Eye-VU-meter-will-be-ready-right-in-time.html)).